# MS Access Query counting instances

Tags: ms-access-2010

---

I have a sample table with following values

```
SNO  |  Mon
-----+-------
100  |  1
101  |  1
102  |  1
100  |  2
101  |  2
102  |  2
100  |  3
101  |  3
```

Now I need a query to count the total sno's which are in 3 months

The result should be 2, as 100 & 101 are in mon 1,2 and 3. However, 102 is only present in mon 1,2.

Thanks,
RK

Answer (score 0):

This Query in theory should work.

```
SELECT 
    tmpTbl.sNo
FROM 
    tmpTbl
GROUP BY 
    tmpTbl.sNo
HAVING 
    Count(tmpTbl.monNo) = (SELECT Count(*) FROM (SELECT tmpTbl.monNo FROM tmpTbl GROUP BY tmpTbl.monNo));
```

The result would be,

```
sNo 
----
100 
101
```

I have used two SubQueries to get the result. Teh both are used in the HAVING clause of the SQL. First SqubQuery (inner most). Will get the number of Unique Month's available in your table, the outer SubQuery will then Count the number of Unique months. So the Overall Query can be translated as `"SELECT the serial number FROM the table HAVING the Count of Month equal to the Number of unique records in the same table"`.

The reason I used SbQuery instead of a number is because of the fact this will also be applicable when your month number increases. Hope this helps !

**EDIT**
Here is the Query for getting the count.

```
SELECT 
    Count(*) As simpleCount 
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        tmpTbl.sNo
    FROM 
        tmpTbl
    GROUP BY 
        tmpTbl.sNo
    HAVING 
        Count(tmpTbl.monNo) = (SELECT Count(*) FROM (SELECT tmpTbl.monNo FROM tmpTbl GROUP BY tmpTbl.monNo))
);
```

Comment: Thanks but this query gives me only the records present in all months. what I need is count of sno which exists in 1 month, 2 months etc..not the mon in the table.

Comment: I understand that, given that Query you could have easily got the count. Anyway, I have edited the code, check the **EDIT** section in my post above.